# Xamarin.Forms and Prism - How to pass data and navigate to another view?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

This's my first question here, so hi everybody.
I'm working on the mobile app in Xamarin.Forms with Prism. I've created ListView where shown data from the database.

When the user clicks in the selected row app should navigate to a new view and pass the selected item from ListView.

```
<ListView x:Name="DefectsBase"
          RowHeight="65"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Defects}"
          ItemSelected="ShowDetailsEvent"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding Refresh}"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
```

Code backend:

```
 async void  ShowDetailsEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        
        var myListView = (ListView)sender;
        var myItem = myListView.SelectedItem;
        var p = new NavigationParameters();
        p.Add("selectedDefect", myItem);
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("DefectDetailsView", p);
  }
```

Unfortunately, the app doesn't respond to pressing the selected row in ListView.

Comment: Is it in code behind or in a view model?

Comment: Just to be sure, set `SelectionMode=Single`

Comment: It's code behind. I am not sure how can I implement event ItemSelected in viewmodel. I've tried that way: create method in viewmodel witch navigate to new model and pass parameter. In code behind view I binding context and tried execute method from viewmodel but I don't know what kind parameter I schould use

Comment: Hi @ARos can you please take a look at my answer, I think it will be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are already using `Prism` and you have a List page with Items and you want to navigate to some details page based on the selected/taped/chosen item which the user taps in the ListView.

The idea is to move as much code and logic as we can to the view model and keep our code-behind. This is pretty easy to solve using `Prism` and `EventToCommand` behaviour.

In the example and answer below, I will show you how to solve this with few lines of code, with a nice code approach.

First of all, I recommend you use `EventToCommand` behaviour, you can include it with prism xmlns, like this: `xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"`, later on, you can use it with ListView.

Remove ItemSelected event from your ListView and move the markup about it to the `<ListView.Behaviors>` part. Here is my code sample for the `ListView` which binds to some `ObserverableCollection` of the Car models:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              ...
        </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" 
                                      Command="{Binding SelectedCarCommand}"
                                      EventArgsParameterPath="Item" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
```

The main part here is `<ListView.Behaviors>`, where you can see that I am binding to the SelectedCarCommand which will be invoked when the user taps on some of the items from the list. I am using the `ItemTapped` event for this and passing the current "taped" item from the list as a parameter.

In order to follow this XAML part in my view model of this page, I have declared the `DelegateCommand` and method which will be called when the command is invoked. The view model part looks like this:

*This is my CarListPageViewModel, take a look at DelegateCommand and SelectedCar method.*

```
public class CarListPageViewModel
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<Car> SelectedCarCommand { get; private set; }

    public CarListPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        // Insert test data into collection of Cars
        Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>(dataProvider.GetData());

        SelectedCarCommand = new DelegateCommand<Car>(SelectedCar);
    }

    private async void SelectedCar(Car selectedCar)
    {
        NavigationParameters navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters
        {
            { "selectedCar", selectedCar }
        };

        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(CarDetailsPage), navigationParameters);
    }
}
```

As you can see we have `DelegateCommand` defined with the type of parameter which will be passed, in my case, this is the Car class, the same class as our items in the ListView.

In the constructor, I did my initialization and defined the method which will be called, that method has a parameter of the type Car.

When the user taps on one of the items in the ListView, SelectedCar (method) will be called and we can pass the data to the next view using `NavigationParameters` and `NavigationService`.

In order to retrieve the passed data we can use `INavigationAware` in the details view model and with the `OnNavigatedTo` method, access the data which is being passed.

*This is my CarDetailsPageViewModel, take a look at `OnNavigatedTo` method.*

```
public class CarDetailsPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private string carTitle;
    public string CarTitle
    {
        get { return carTitle; }
        set { SetProperty(ref carTitle, value); }
    }

    private string photoUrl;
    public string PhotoUrl
    {
        get { return photoUrl; }
        set { SetProperty(ref photoUrl, value); }
    }

    public CarDetailsPageViewModel() {  }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.ContainsKey("selectedCar"))
        {
            Car car = parameters.GetValue<Car>("selectedCar");

            if (car != null)
            {
                CarTitle = $"{car.Make} {car.Model}";
                PhotoUrl = car.PhotoUrl;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters) { }
}
```

From this answer and example, you can see:

- How to, use `EventToCommand` behaviour with `ListView`
- Define and use `DelegateCommand` with passing parameter
- How to navigate to another view and pass navigation parameter and
- ... finally how to access the passed data.

Code and this sample you can find on my GitHub profile [here](https://github.com/almirvuk/ExempliGratia/tree/master/ExempliGratia.Mobile/ExempliGratia.Mobile).

Hope this answer was helpful for you!

Wishing you lots of luck with coding!