# Xamarin forms get data from another view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I have 2 views. In the main one I enter bookshelf's barcode and book's barcode which I place on the previously scanned bookshelf. After the book barcode is entered it shows in Entry field with the name of the book.
There is also a button that will open second view in which I can add new book to database(id, name, author and generate barcode).

How can I get the generated barcode and the book name from the second view and use it in the main view?

Comment: Are you using any framework like Prism? Are you using MVVM architecture? What does your code look like? It's difficult to provide an answer without any details.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. I use both Prism and MVVM. It's hard to provide the code since the second view is not implemented yet and the main view doesn't contain anything that related to my question

Comment: if you're using PRISM it's helpful to add that tag so people know.  And without code we can only provide a generic example.  Or you could refer to the dozens of samples from PRISM or the hundreds of samples here and in the Xamarin docs.   Keep in mind that Xamarin pages are just C# classes - you can pass data on the constructor, use properties and methods, custom events, etc.

Comment: [Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67350735/199364) using Prism, that shows how to pass data to the second view. Should be possible to use its techniques to get that data back. One technique is to pass an `Action callMeBack` to the second view. When the second view has the result it does `callMeBack(theResult);`, thus executing whatever Action the main view wants to be performed with that result. An alternative is to create an `event` in the second view, which main view adds (`+=`) an `event handler` to.

Answer (score 0):

I've been passing a callback `Action` in the constructor of the child page to do this exact thing lately (as @ToolmakerSteve metioned in the comments). Here's an example:

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage {
    public MainPage() {}

    private async Task OpenChildPageAsync(){
        var page = new ChildPage(AddNewBook);
        await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    }

    private void AddNewBook(Book newBook){
        //do something with the new book
    }
}

public class ChildPage : ContentPage {

    private readonly Action<Book> _callback;

    public ChildPage(Action<Book> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void OnBookSelected(Book selectedBook){
        //this method might be called when a Book is selected in the UI for example
        _callback?.Invoke(selectedBook);
    }
}

public class Book {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Prism or no Prism? In the context of Prism, what's the benefit of `Navigation` over `INavigationService`?

Comment: I'm using the default INavigation that comes with Xamarin.Forms but you can use whatever navigation mechanism Prism has as well.